# Dynamically add "select" with "default Text" in table through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

How can I add dynamical drop down selects(set default selecte!) in dynamically table by using javascript and JSON.

I want to add many selects (dropdown) to every row in my table, and set the default text in the select. The table is created by using javascript append and has dynamic content imported from JSON files using Jquery.

I can import all content successfully, however the dropdowns can not set selected . I would appriciate if you guys can assist me to have the dropdown select. Thank you very much!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
...
$(target).append("<tr style='height:150px'>" +
                        "<td><input type='checkbox'></td>" +
                        "<td>pics</td>" +
                        "<td>" + menuItemName + "</td>" +
                        "<td id='"+menuItemId+"'>" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td class='menuItemPrice'>" + menuData.Categories[c].Items[i].Price + "</td>" +
                        "<td>mount</td>" +
                        "</tr>"
                    );
...

for (var o = 0; o < menuData.Categories[c].Items[i].Options.length; o++) {
    var inputs = {isFirst:   firstOption,
                 optionId:   menuData.Categories[c].Items[i].Options[o].MenuItemOptionId,
                 optionName: menuData.Categories[c].Items[i].Options[o].MenuItemOptionName,
                 price:      menuData.Categories[c].Items[i].Options[o].Price
                 };
    $('#'+menuItemId).append("<div><select"+
                                "<option value='1'>small</option>" +
                                "<option value='2'>mid</option>" +
                                "<option value='3'>big</option>" +
                                "<option value='4'>very big</option>"+
                                "</select></div>"

                            );
```

here I want to set the default Select but can not success,please help me,Thank You!

```
$('#'+menuItemId).children(':selected').text(inputs.optionName);//here just can show the last size.
```

HTML

```
...
<tbody id="sortable">
```

Comment: concatenating strings of HTML is a terrible idea. You should be using `document.createElement`

Comment: You should probably store `menuData.Categories[c].Items[i]` in a variable

Answer (score 1):

First, your `select` tag does not have a closing angle bracket (>) so the HTML is malformed. It should be something like this:

```
$('#'+menuItemId).append("<div><select>"+
```

Second, you should use `find` instead of `children` because what you are looking for is multiple levels below the element identified by your selector, like so:

```
$('#'+menuItemId).find(':selected').text(optionName);
```

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/tLddsL2p/1/

Comment: Thanks!Using your methods help me a lot.

Comment: @SuYungCheng In that case, please upvote and/or accept the answer, thanks. :-)